# d3 csv load api change

Tags: csv, d3.js

It's been awhile since I've used d3, and I was reading how the old syntax for loading a csv:
`d3.csv("path/to/csv.csv", function(x){...})` no longer worked. But I'm using v7 from this location: `http://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js` and that syntax works, while attempting to use the new method which people are saying has been the syntax since v5 with promises:
`d3.csv("path/to/csv.csv").then(function(x){...})` gives the error `Uncaught TypeError: d3.csv(...).then is not a function`

Not really a huge deal just a bit confused, did d3 change the api of their csv function between v5 and v7?

Answer (score 0):

> did d3 change the api of their csv function between v5 and v7?

I think the answer to that specific question is *no*. In fact, the change happened when V5 was released, according to the [release notes](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/main/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50).

Perhaps, you're thinking back to V4?

Comment: Sorry forgot to go back and respond to this. The issue ended up being some sort of interference with a plotly script I was including. Maybe the plotly library sources d3 v4 and that overrode v7? Either way my project ended up not needing plotly anymore so once I removed that source the d3 code ended up working exactly as expected for v7.